# Javascript for form validation isn't functioning

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

defined the script in the head of my html file but still doesn't function is it because the action for my form leads to a php file?

```
<html>
    <head>
          <script>
         function validateForm()
          {
          var x=document.forms["myForm"]["food_name"].value;
           if (x==null || x=="")
            {
           alert("Food name must be filled out");
            return false;
             }
            </script>
<title> my title is going here </title>
</head>
<body>

 <form name="myForm"  action="http://xxxxxxxxx/~xxxxxxxx/file/phpfile.php" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
        <b>foodName:</b> <input type="text" name="food_name"><br>
        <b>Food Type:</b> <input type="text" name="food_type"><br>
        <b>Total:</b> <input type="text" name="total"><br>
        <b>Available:</b> <input type="text" name="available"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body` -> `} </script>`

Comment: Also **return** `onsubmit="return validateForm();"` else form would submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the missing curly braces `}` for the validateForm function and update onsubmit to this

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

other wise it will submit the form even if validation is failed

check http://jsfiddle.net/Thu69/

Answer (score 1):

you have missing brace in your `validateForm` function